# Adding an Array Field using FileHelpers DelimitedClassBuilder

Tags: c#, filehelpers

How do I do this dynamically using DelimitedClassBuilder so that the columns in the file can expand but not break my program?

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MyRecord
{
    public string Name;

    [FieldOptional, FieldArrayLength(0, 100)]
    public string[] I_DONT_CARE_WHAT_COMES_AFTER_THIS;
}
```

i.e. how do I finish this:

```
var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("xyz", ",");
cb.AddField("Name", "string");
... how do I add the array field here?
Type type = cb.CreateRecordClass();
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(type);
```

Comment: did you get final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. The best I can find is:

```
var cb = new DelimitedClassBuilder("xyz", ",");
cb.AddField("Name", "string");
cb.AddFields(100);
foreach (var field in cb.Fields.Where(f => f.FieldName.StartsWith("Field")))
{
    field.FieldOptional = true;             
}
var type = cb.CreateRecordClass();
var engine = new DelimitedFileEngine(type);
```

I can't get it to work with

```
cb.AddField("I_DONT_CARE", typeof(string[]));
```

Nor with

```
cb.AddField("I_DONT_CARE", typeof(string[]).FullName);
```

both of which ought to work.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried the second part but was getting runtime error. But the first part is what I was looking for. Works perfectly.